# What ports does RabbitMQ use?

Tags: rabbitmq, port

What ports does RabbitMQ Server use or need to have open on the firewall for a cluster of nodes?

My `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-env` is set below which I'm assuming are needed (35197).

```
SERVER_ERL_ARGS="+K true +A30 +P 1048576 \   
-kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] \  
-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 35197 \   
-kernel inet_dist_listen_max 35197"
```

I haven't touched the `rabbitmq.config` to set a custom `tcp_listener` so it should be listening on the default 5672.

Here are the relevant netstat lines:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369           0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      728/epmd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35197          0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      5126/beam
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                :::*                LISTEN      5126/beam
```

My questions are:

1. for other nodes to be able to connect to the cluster, do all 3 ports 4369, 5672 and 35197 need to be open?
2. Why isn't 5672 running on tcp and not just tcp6?

Comment: Might get more response on ServerFault instead of StackOverflow but I'm glad you posted it here as it is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 177, accepted):

PORT 4369: Erlang makes use of a Port Mapper Daemon (epmd) for resolution of node names in a cluster. Nodes must be able to reach each other and the port mapper daemon for clustering to work.

PORT 35197
set by inet_dist_listen_min/max Firewalls must permit traffic in this range to pass between clustered nodes

RabbitMQ Management console:

- PORT 15672 for RabbitMQ version 3.x
- PORT 55672 for RabbitMQ pre 3.x

Make sure that the [rabbitmq_management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#getting-started) is enabled, otherwise you won't be able to access management console on those ports.

- PORT `5672` RabbitMQ main port (AMQP)
- PORT `5671` TLS-encrypted AMQP (if enabled)

For a cluster of nodes, they must be open to each other on `35197`, `4369` and `5672`.

For any servers that want to use the message queue, only `5672` (or possibly `5671`) is required.

Comment: Looks like the clustering ports are 4369 and 25672 from: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

Answer (score 85):

### What ports is RabbitMQ using?

Default: 5672, the manual has the answer.  It's defined in the `RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT` variable.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#define-environment-variables

**The number might be differently if changed by someone in the rabbitmq configuration file:**

```
vi /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
```

**Ask the nmap if it can see it:**

```
sudo nmap -p 1-65535 localhost

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-19 13:50 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00041s latency).
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
443/tcp   open          https
5672/tcp  open          amqp
15672/tcp open  unknown
35102/tcp open  unknown
59440/tcp open  unknown
```

Oh look, 5672, and 15672

**Ask netstat if it can see it:**

```
netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672               0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55672               0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::5672                     :::*                   LISTEN
```

Oh look 5672.

**lsof to see ports:**

```
eric@dev ~$ sudo lsof -i | grep beam
beam.smp  21216    rabbitmq   17u  IPv4 33148214      0t0  TCP *:55672 (LISTEN)
beam.smp  21216    rabbitmq   18u  IPv4 33148219      0t0  TCP *:15672 (LISTEN)
```

**use nmap from a different machine, find out if 5672 is open:**

```
sudo nmap -p 5672 10.0.1.71
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-19 13:19 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.71
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5672/tcp open  amqp
MAC Address: 0A:40:0E:8C:75:6C (Unknown)    
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

**Try to connect to a port manually with telnet, 5671 is CLOSED:**

```
telnet localhost 5671
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

**Try to connect to a port manually with telnet, 5672 is OPEN:**

```
telnet localhost 5672
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**Check your firewall:**

```
sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

It should tell you what ports are made open:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
```

**Reapply your firewall:**

```
sudo service iptables restart
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
iptables: Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. If anything, you've gone overboard a little.

Comment: In case somebody was wondering - by default rabbitmq will only bind 4369 port to interface you specify within rabbitmq-env.conf; If you wanted to permitt all rabbitmq-related traffic through specified interface (like myself - through dedicated openvpn link) then you will have to configure rabbitmq to pass all other traffic through that interface within rabbitmq.conf (otherwise other ports won't be bound to interface of your choice but will be listening on all ports instead)

Answer (score 23):

**To find out what ports rabbitmq uses**:

```
$ epmd -names
```

**Outputs:**

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name rabbit at port 25672
```

**Run these as root:**

```
lsof -i :4369
lsof -i :25672
```

[More about epmd options.](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html)

Comment: `lsof` is painfully slow... and it requires root privileges. You can do the same, much more rapidly, with `netstat -an | egrep '\.(4369|25672).*LISTEN'`

Comment: does it really require root? I was able to run it fine as a normal user. Maybe something changed in the recent versions?

Answer (score 18):

Port Access

Firewalls and other security tools may prevent RabbitMQ from binding to a port. When that happens, RabbitMQ will fail to start. Make sure the following ports can be opened:

4369: epmd, a peer discovery service used by RabbitMQ nodes and CLI tools

5672, 5671: used by AMQP 0-9-1 and 1.0 clients without and with TLS

25672: used by Erlang distribution for inter-node and CLI tools communication and is allocated from a dynamic range (limited to a single port by default, computed as AMQP port + 20000). See networking guide for details.

15672: HTTP API clients and rabbitmqadmin (only if the management plugin is enabled)

61613, 61614: STOMP clients without and with TLS (only if the STOMP plugin is enabled)

1883, 8883: (MQTT clients without and with TLS, if the MQTT plugin is enabled

15674: STOMP-over-WebSockets clients (only if the Web STOMP plugin is enabled)

15675: MQTT-over-WebSockets clients (only if the Web MQTT plugin is enabled)

Reference doc:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Check `\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log`. If you have a log file there search for `started TCP listener on [::]`.

It should tell you on which port rabbitMq is running. Look for the last entry.

Disclaimer: not the best way to find port, as there might be a chance the port has been changed in the mean time.